# Efficient way to find closest vector from 10M of samples

Tags: python, algorithm, computational-geometry, in-memory-database, computation-theory

Say I have a database of 10 000 000 of 100-dimensional vectors:

```
X1 = [x1_1, ..., x1_100]
X2 = [x2_1, ..., x2_100]
...
X1000000 = [x1000000_1, ..., x1000000_100]
```

And I have input vector Y :

```
Y = [y1, ..., y100]
```

What is the most efficient way to find closest vector Xi to Y in sense of euclidean distance?

Comment: If you only have a single vector, can't you just write a vectorized numpy function to calculate the euclidian distance then call `np.min()`? Don't suppose it gets any faster than that

Comment: @Jeff , I need to extract each vector from the database and execute np.min() for 10 million times? There is no way faster to do this?

Comment: Use **K-D tree** for nearest neighbour search in k dimension which as time complexity of logn for search

Comment: Load all your `x` vectors as a 2D numpy. Create a `np.vectorize()` function that finds euclidean distance from your single `y`. Call your vectorized function on your `x` 2D array, yielding a 1D `results` array. Lastly call `np.min(results)`. Just need to call it once.

Comment: Girish's answer may be better, but in general I don't think you can write any algorithm in pure python that beats the time complexity of standard libraries such as `numpy` since python abstracts away a lot of the nitty gritty stuff regarding data structures. If you really want eek out that extra performance by sacrificing readability, you might have to go for a language like C++.

Comment: @Jeff, thank you for your help! But I think usage of K-D tree is the fastest way to solve this problem.

Comment: Looks like it, i think the `numpy` method runs at least linear time. With 1 million vectors I suppose it'd be worth to check out sklearn's K-D tree implementation. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html

Comment: Don't use a standard kD-tree. Due to the "curse of dimensionality" issue, it will be slower than exhaustive search ! kD-trees are notoriously inefficient for high dimensions, and certainly not O(Log N). Consider using the best-bin-first strategy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_bin_first#:~:text=Best%20bin%20first%20is%20a,indexing%20higher%2Ddimensional%20spaces%20possible.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
def find_CD(X,y):
  return ​return​ spatial.distance.euclidean(X,y)
```

in the main

```
listt=[]
vic=[x1,x2,.....,X1000000]
for i in range(len(vic)):
 listt.append(find_CD(vic[i],y)
```

and find the min values index

```
listt.index(min(listt))
```

Comment: Thank you! But I think the execution of euclidian distance for 10 million times is not so effective. I like the solution with the K-D tree @Girish Dattatray Hegde proposed.

Comment: @corvax: make sure to implement both exhaustive search and kD-tree search and compare them (see my remark above).

Comment: @corvax As mentioned by others, with 100 dimensions a KD tree is basically useless. KD tree works best when `N >> (much greater than) 2^D`, where `D` is the number of dimensions. With 10 million points, `D` must be well under `23` for it to be worth while, otherwise the tree will be very "shallow" and you won't get the benefit of it.